# Eliminar texto de html con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando limpiar una fecha de html con Javascript pero no lo consigo
Me gustaria quitar `GMT+0000 (hora estándar de Europa occidental)` y esto es lo que he intentado:
Fichero HTML que devuelve la fecha en el siguiente formato: `Sat Nov 12 2022 19:57:06 GMT+0000 (hora estándar de Europa occidental)`

```
<p class="card-text" id="fecha">
     Fecha:
     <%= i.createdAt %>
</p>
```

Javascript que quiero que deje la fecha en el formato 12/11/2022 o al menos que elimine todo el texto inecesario. Esto es lo que he conseguido:

```
<script>
    const date = document.querySelector("#fecha")
    date.replace("GMT+0000 (hora estándar de Europa occidental)", "")
</script>
```

Gracias de antemano, pd: Este codigo no hace nada :(

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder al texto de la etiqueta `<p>` tienes que usar `date.innerText`

```
const date = document.querySelector("#fecha")
date.innerText = date.innerText.replace(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Con este ejemplo puedes obtener solo la fecha sin la demás descripción. es usando simplemente **toLocaleDateString()**

```js
let fecha = new Date();
document.querySelector(".fecha").innerText = fecha.toLocaleDateString();
```

```html
<p class="fecha"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que obtienes en tu etiqueta `<p>` lo siguiente:

```
Sat Nov 12 2022 19:57:06 GMT+0000 (hora estándar de Europa occidental)
```

Tendrías que ingresar al `id` de la etiqueta con la propiedad `innerText` y aplicar tu método para reemplazar, por ejemplo:

```js
fecha = document.getElementById("fecha").innerText;
resultado = document.getElementById("result");

result = fecha.replace("GMT+0000 (hora estándar de Europa occidental)", "")
resultado.innerHTML += result;
```

```html
<p class="card-text" id="fecha" style="display:none">
  Sat Nov 12 2022 19:57:06 GMT+0000 (hora estándar de Europa occidental)
</p>
<p id="result">Fecha: </p>
```